# Laravel 5.2 throws HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel-5, http-status-code-500

I am using laravel 5.2 setup of pre-built project. I am looking to show errors on browser window for any issue happens. I know a simple step to  do that which is to modify the `APP_DEBUG` to true in `.env` file which is pointed by `app.php` config file with parameter `debug`. I did check that.

Additionally,

1. I added `ini_set` property in index file to `display_errors` as `true`.
2. Along with this, I commented all the `$dontReport` exceptions from `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file-

   ```
   AuthorizationException::class,
   HttpException::class,
   ModelNotFoundException::class,
   ValidationException::class,
   ```
3. Given 777 permission to my project directory.

At the end, all these crazy methods didn't workout. I tried all I was aware of. Looking for help from you guys.

Comment: Setting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file should suffice. If you changed it make sure to run `php artisan config:cache` to read in and cache the new settings

Comment: Is there anything written to your server's error log?

Comment: Silly question but is PHP code actually running?

Comment: @NicoHaase it successfully writes the expected logs to laravel.log file located in storage. Only don't show on browser.

Comment: @kerbholz, I tried with php artisan config:cache but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1/2/3 is not necessary for Laravel and you should revert those changes.

Only APP_DEBUG=true in your .env file is required. If you are working on a local machine you should also set APP_ENV=local. To locate the 500 error without the browser you can always go look in the log file directly which is located at storage/logs.

Comment: I already have `APP_ENV` set to `local`, and `APP_DEBUG` to `true` and the `laravel.log` file always logs the errors correctly, but I am looking to show them on browser.

Comment: @DIGVJSS if you did that it should show in the browser. But obviously only on the endpoint where the error occurs. Commenting-out the $dontReport error does not solve anything since none of those are 500 errors anyway.